# How to remove photos without masters from library in OS X Photos app?

Tags: macos, photos, library

I was cleaning my drive and removed many file duplicates. I removed many photo masters (originals) from OS X Photos app library, but when I open Photos app I saw that all photos are still in my library. Is there any way to delete photos without masters from my library?

Answer (score 2):

Photos should detect when changes have been made to the library and prepare it for you. See [Photos has attempted to repair the library](https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/photos-has-attempted-to-repair-the-library/).

You can force Photos to repair the library if it doesn't do it automatically:

> You can force Photos to try to repair the library by holding option and command (⌥⌘) whilst launching Photos. Photos.app will try to repair the library and it may ask you for administrator privileges.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help.